# How do I find the differences between two tables with the same columns but different values?

Tags: sql

I have two tables with customer data, both with the exact same columns and same customer IDs.

Both tables were extracted from the db with a 3 month gap in between so I expect that some of the values for the columns will have changed for some of the customers.

The table schema looks like:

```
customerID | location | phone | address
```

The customer ID is always the same but location, phone and address can change. Some of the values can also be NULL but most of them are not null values.

How do I write a SQL script that can detect these changes - and count them up so I can visualize it better?

So far I've got:

```
with t1 as (
    select distinct customerID
        , phone
    from table1
),
t2 as (
    select distinct a.customerID
        , b.phone
    from table1 a 
    left join table2 b on a.customerID = b.customerID
)
select customerID, phone
from t1
except
select customerID, phone
from t2
```

I'm not too sure if this is the correct logic, if someone could come up with a more efficient solution.

Comment: Why have you tagged 2 RDBMS products? Please only tag the one of interest.

Comment: I've removed them, please add a single RDBMS tag back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to count.
I created the sample tables and attached a screenshot of the result to this post as well.

```
SELECT a.[cust_id]
,sum((case when trim(a.phone) <> trim(b.phone) then 1 else 0 end)) 
 count_of_phone_changes
,sum((case when trim(a.[Location]) <> trim(b.[location]) then 1 else 0 end)) 
count_of_location_changes
,sum((Case when trim(a.[address]) <> trim(b.[address]) then 1 else 0 end)) 
count_of_address_changes
 FROM [dbo].[Table_1] a
left join [dbo].[Table_2] b on
a.cust_id = b.cust_id
group by a.cust_id
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nPiD.png]

Comment: note i used "trim" to remove the spaces to make sure comparison is accurate as i was storing most of it as char in my sample tables. 
You may choose to use or drop it

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your code clearly,especially using cte.
But you can using operator EXCEPT to find values(phone and etc) in Table1 which isn't located in Table2 (or vice versa - just swap Table1 and Table2 in EXCEPT blocks).
There's 3 blocks (except) because you want to know count each type of difference (phone,location,addres).
After getting absenting values, just using SUM+UNION to get values in one line (for each customer_id). Also,if there's will be NULL value, I use operator coalesce to replace it with empty string

```
select
CustomerId,
SUM (CASE WHEN TypeDifference='DiffPhone' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)CountDiffPhone,
SUM (CASE WHEN TypeDifference='DiffLocation' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)CountDiffLocation,
SUM (CASE WHEN TypeDifference='DiffAddress' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)CountDiffAddress
FROM
(
select CustomerId,  'DiffPhone' As TypeDifference from
  (
    select CustomerId,COALESCE(phone,'')phone from Table1
    except
    select CustomerId,COALESCE(phone,'') from Table2
  ) X 

UNION ALL

select customerID,'DiffLocation' from 
  (
    select customerID,COALESCE(location,'')location from Table1
    except
    select customerID,COALESCE(location,'') from Table2
   ) Y 

UNION ALL

select customerID,'DiffAddress' from 
(
   select customerID,COALESCE(address,'')location from Table1
   except
   select customerID,COALESCE(address,'') from Table2
) Z

)
T
GROUP BY CustomerId
```

Comment: nut_flush, do you run it?